# Mixing colors program

Tags: python, if-statement

Prompt:

The colors red, blue, and yellow are known as the primary colors because they
cannot be made by mixing other colors. When you mix two primary colors, you get
a secondary color:
When you mix red and blue, you get purple.
When you mix red and yellow, you get orange.
When you mix blue and yellow, you get green.

Design a program that prompts the user to enter the names of two primary colors,
one at a time. If the user enters anything other than "red," "blue," or
"yellow," the program should print "You didn't input two primary colors."
Otherwise, it should print something in the format:

"When you mix red and blue, you get purple."
(Assuming the user entered "red" and "blue”.)

My program kept getting wrong standard output

Here's what I wrote:

```
primary_colora = input("Enter primary color:")
primary_colorb = input("Enter primary color:")
primary_colors = primary_colora or primary_colorb

if primary_colora == (red, blue, yellow):
    primary_colora = True

elif primary_colorb == (red, blue, yellow):
    primary_colorb = True

elif primary_colors == red or blue:
    print("When you mix red and blue, you get purple")

elif primary_colors == yellow or blue:
    print("When you mix yellow and blue, you get green")

elif primary_colors == yellow or red:
    print("When you mix yellow and red, you get orange")

else: print("You didn't input two primary colors.")
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your statements to match the colors as strings and not as variables -

```
if primary_colora in ['red', 'blue', 'yellow']:
```

and so on...

Comment: thats one of many problems ... im pretty sure `primary_colors = primary_colora or primary_colorb` does not do what he thinks it does ...

Answer (score 0):

I looked around and found much simpler way to combine and & or in the statements

here's the code

```
primary_color1 = input("Enter primary color:")
primary_color2 = input("Enter primary color:")

if (primary_color1 == "red" and primary_color2 == "blue") or (primary_color1 == "blue" and primary_color2 == "red"):
    print("When you mix red and blue, you get purple.")

 elif (primary_color1 == "blue" and primary_color2 == "yellow") or (primary_color1 == "yellow" and primary_color2 == "blue"):
    print("When you mix blue and yellow, you get green.")

elif (primary_color1 == "yellow" and primary_color2 == "red") or (primary_color1 == "red" and primary_color2 == "yellow"):
    print("When you mix yellow and red, you get orange.")

else: print("You didn't input two primary colors.")
```

Answer (score 0):

the code was almost correct I added a few things that made it work

```
primary_colora = input("Enter primary color:")
primary_colorb = input("Enter primary color:")
primary_colors = primary_colora or primary_colorb

if primary_colora == ['red', 'blue', 'yellow']:
primary_colora = True

elif primary_colorb == ['red', 'blue', 'yellow']:
primary_colorb = True

elif primary_colors == 'red' or 'blue':
print("When you mix red and blue, you get purple")

elif primary_colors == 'yellow' or 'blue':
print("When you mix yellow and blue, you get green")

elif primary_colors == 'yellow' or 'red':
print("When you mix yellow and red, you get orange")

else: print("You didn't input two primary colors.")
```

Answer (score 0):

That is my variation. If it is possible to simplify the code, give me a clue .

```
color1=str(input('Enter first primary color: '))
color2=str(input('Enter second primary color: '))

RED='red'
BLUE='blue'
YELLOW='yellow'


if color1 != BLUE and color1 != RED and color1 != YELLOW:
   print('Error')
elif color2 != BLUE and color2 != RED and color2 != YELLOW :
   print('Error')
elif color1 == BLUE and color2 == BLUE:
   print('Error')
elif color1 == YELLOW and color2 == YELLOW:
   print('Error')
elif color1 == RED and color2 == RED:
   print('Error')
elif (color1 == RED and color2 == BLUE) or (color1 == BLUE and color2 == RED):
   print('Purple')
elif (color1 == RED and color2 == YELLOW) or (color1 == YELLOW and color2 == RED):
   print('Orange')
else:
   print('Green')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
primary1 = input("Enter primary color:")
primary2 = input("Enter primary color:")

if (primary1.lower() == "red" and primary2.lower() == "blue") or (primary1.lower() == "blue" and primary2.lower() == "red"):
    secondary = "purple"
    print(f"When you mix {primary1.lower()} and {primary2.lower()}, you get {secondary}.")
elif (primary1.lower() == "red" and primary2.lower() == "yellow") or (primary1.lower() == "yellow" and primary2.lower() == "red"):
    secondary = "orange"
    print(f"When you mix {primary1.lower()} and {primary2.lower()}, you get {secondary}.")
elif (primary1.lower() == "blue" and primary2.lower() == "yellow") or (primary1.lower() == "yellow" and primary2.lower() == "blue"):
    secondary = "green"
    print(f"When you mix {primary1.lower()} and {primary2.lower()}, you get {secondary}.")
else:
    print("You didn't input two primary colors.")
```

Comment: This looks like the same answer as https://stackoverflow.com/a/32675255 apart from the conversion to lower-case. When you adapt another answer you should attribute it.

Answer (score 0):

Took a screenshot in PyCharm.

[image: Primary Colors screenshot]

that's how I finally got it correct.

```py
primary1 = input("Enter primary color:")
primary2 = input("Enter primary color:")

if (primary1.lower() == "red" and primary2.lower() == "blue") or (primary1.lower() == "blue" and                                                                
 primary2.lower() == "red"):
   secondary = "purple"
   print(f"When you mix {primary1.lower()} and {primary2.lower()}, you get {secondary}.")
elif (primary1.lower() == "red" and primary2.lower() == "yellow") or (primary1.lower() == "yellow" and
                                                                      primary2.lower() == "red"):
    secondary = "orange"
    print(f"When you mix {primary1.lower()} and {primary2.lower()}, you get {secondary}.")
elif (primary1.lower() == "blue" and primary2.lower() == "yellow") or (primary1.lower() == "yellow" and
                                                                       primary2.lower() == "blue"):
    secondary = "green"
    print(f"When you mix {primary1.lower()} and {primary2.lower()}, you get {secondary}.")
else:
    print("You didn't input two primary colors.")
```

Comment: Please, format you answer properly.

Answer (score 0):

```py
while True:
    color1 = input("Enter the first primary color (red, blue, or yellow): ").lower()
    color2 = input("Enter the second primary color (red, blue, or yellow):").lower()

    if color1 == color2:
        print("You can't choose the same primary colors in both variables.")
        break
    elif color1 not in ["red", "blue", "yellow"] or color2 not in ["red", "blue", "yellow"]:
        print("Error: Please enter valid primary colors.")
    else:
        # Determine the secondary color
        if color1 == "red" and color2 == "blue" or color1 == "blue" and color2 == "red":
            secondary_color = "purple"
        elif color1 == "red" and color2 == "yellow" or color1 == "yellow" and color2 == "red":
            secondary_color = "orange"
        elif color1 == "blue" and color2 == "yellow" or color1 == "yellow" and color2 == "blue":
            secondary_color = "green"

        # Display the resulting secondary color
        print(f"The secondary color is {secondary_color}.")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly new to the coding scene, but I came up with this and it also worked for my class

```
if (primary1 == 'red' and primary2 == 'blue') or (primary1 == 'blue' and primary2 == 'red'):
    print("When you mix " +primary1+ " and " +primary2+ ", you get purple.")
elif (primary1 == 'red' and primary2 == 'yellow') or (primary1 == 'yellow' and primary2 == 'red'):
    print("When you mix " +primary1+ " and " +primary2+ ", you get orange.")
elif (primary1 == 'blue' and primary2 == 'yellow') or (primary1 == 'yellow' and primary2 == 'blue'):
    print("When you mix " +primary1+ " and " +primary2+ ", you get green.")
else:
    print("You didn't input two primary colors.")
```